# How to get the SOAP message header in JAVA

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, security, soap-client

Hello:) I have a web service written on Java, running on Apache 7 using CXF and I want the service to be able to read the information from the SOAP Header. Also I want the user to be able to put his username and password in the SOAP Header. I've read a lot of posts and stuff but i just don't have a clue from where to begin. I would be very pleased if you help me :)